# Changing file modification time for tar archive members

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tar

I have a tar archive on an NTFS drive on a windows machine which contains a folder with files residing on a drive on my linux machine. I try to update the archive from a bash shell script from my linux machine with the -u (--update) tar option, so that only new versions of archive members are appended to the archive. However, due to the "time skew" between file times on two filesystems, tar appends to the archive ALL the files in the folder, even if the folder does not contain any new versions of files at all.

So the problem is: how to add to an archive on machine B only new version of files from a folder on machine A in conditions when there is time skew between machines?

Is there a way to solve this problem so that mtimes of individual files in archive were preserved or changed insignificantly (e.g. adjusted 10 minutes ahead to negate the time skew)? This probably can be accomplished by calling tar individually for appending each file, but is there a more optimal solution?

Maybe there is a way to change mtime individually for each file when it is added to the archive? The option --after-date for appending only files modified after certain date apparently is not quite suitable filter for this task.

Comment: Yes you can fix it easily.  Setup ntp and fix your times up!

Comment: How and why is `--after-date` not suitable?

Comment: @John Have synced Windows to Linux and vice versa - doesn't fix the problem. The archive after updating contains files with identical modification times. Don't know why tar adds them.

Comment: @Felix --after-date is not suitable because the folder can contain new versions of files with modification time earler that "after-date".

Comment: @AlBerger but does that not simply mean that you need to choose an earlier `after-date`?

Comment: @Felix What date could be choosen, given that all files in the folder to archive have different modification time?

Comment: One would assume that the time of the previous script run would be adequate. Files with earlier mtimes are have been appended previously. All other files are newer.

Comment: @Felix This is the simplest case. There can be cases when after the last backup new versions of files are added to the directory with modification time earlier than the last backup time, but later than mtime of the existing file. But anyways, I decided to went with rsync, which allow to handle these cases properly.